# Pandas ETL: How to manage column mapping of two large tables in a easy way?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I have a scenario where I need to do a ETL between 2 large tables( more than 100 columns each table ), and the columns names are all different between the two tables, even when the value represented is the same. The order between same columns( same value stored, not same columnname ) is different. The table2 has all the table1 columns, using different names, with few more columns. And the table generate millions of rows daily, so I need bulk insert. Ex:

Table1 has a schema beginning in A until Z. Table2 beginning in 1 until 30, but in value mapping:

```
Table1( not ordered):    Table2( ordered ).
columnD  -------->       ( column1 in Table2 ).
columnE  -------->       ( column2 in Table2 ).
columnW  -------->       ( column3 in Table2 ).
...                      ( column4 not exists in Table1 ).
column G -------->       ( column5 in Table2 ).
....
```

data flow order:
table1 -> dataframe -> csv( for bulk insert ) -> table2

My question is, how to deal with this column mapping in a easy, in a beautifil way, and most important, with good performance( more 100 columns and millions rows daily )? Renaming and reorderer the columns in dataframe? Creating a second dataframe with table2 columns name and passing row by row, between dataframes? Creating classes extending dataframe? Mapping at the bulk insert time? Other way?

This is a proof of concept, we actually use SSIS to migrate data between the 2 tables, but we are testing do the same thing with Pandas trying to not lose performance.

Best Regards,
Luis

Comment: What happens in your ETL with `Table2.column4`, which doesn't exist in `Table1`?

Comment: inspectorG4dget. This happens in two scenarios, the first is getting foreign key of other table, and the second is derived calculation of other columns( Ex: colunm1 + colunm2 )

Answer (score 0):

You should define a column mapping and then merge them.  For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

COL_MAP = dict(zip(np.arange(0,4), list("abcd")))
vals = np.random.choice(np.arange(4), 4, replace=False)
df1 = pd.DataFrame([10*vals], columns=vals)
df2 = pd.DataFrame([range(0,4)], columns=list("abcd"))
df1 = df1.rename(columns=COL_MAP)
df3 = pd.concat([df2, df1])
```

inputs:

df1

```
   0   2   1   3
0  0  20  10  30
```

df2

```
   a  b  c  d
0  0  1  2  3
```

output, df3:

```
   a   b   c   d
0  0   1   2   3
0  0  10  20  30
```

You will need to define (or generate) `COL_MAP`.  Unless the mapping changes frequently (in that case *that* is the problem to address), you just hand-code COL_MAP once and store it as a constant.